# Starting heroku delayed_job workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, delayed-job

I'm trying to follow https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job to set up delayed_jobs.

> If you don’t see your worker you may need to scale it up with the
>   heroku command:

```
$ heroku ps:scale worker=1
```

When do I have to run this, every time I deploy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to your app on Heroku, under the `resource` tab, you will see active dynos.

Alternatively, from the terminal, if you run:

```
$ heroku ps
```

You will get a list of all your active dynos.

So, provided that there is no worker dyno, you can now add one and scale it up.

Or if there is a worker dyno but at a `0` (zero) scale, then you can scale it up to one with your command above:

```
$ heroku ps:scale worker=1
```

Note however that a worker dyno will work with/for a [scheduler addon.](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/scheduler)

Comment: Ok cool, I see that I have a enabled web dyno and a disabled hobby worker dyno.  So you need a worker dyno to run delayed_jobs?

Comment: you could have your worker run automatically, but including it in your `Procfile`. Check out `foreman` for more info. Also, you can spin up workers on demand and have them not run until needed, using the gem `workless`